# searching theough a nested JSON data with python

Tags: python, json, django

i have a sample json file from a webhook response and i will want to extract just two data set from the JSON how can i do that using python. assuming i  want to get the subscription code, and plan code values. thanks in anticipation

```
  "event": "subscription.create",
  "data": {
    "domain": "test",
    "status": "active",
    "subscription_code": "SUB_vsyqdmlzble3uii",
    "amount": 50000,
    "cron_expression": "0 0 28 * *",
    "next_payment_date": "2016-05-19T07:00:00.000Z",
    "open_invoice": null,
    "createdAt": "2016-03-20T00:23:24.000Z",
    "plan": {
      "name": "Monthly retainer",
      "plan_code": "PLN_gx2wn530m0i3w3m",
      "description": null,
      "amount": 50000,
      "interval": "monthly",
      "send_invoices": true,
      "send_sms": true,
      "currency": "NGN"
    },
    "authorization": {
      "authorization_code": "AUTH_96xphygz",
      "bin": "539983",
      "last4": "7357",
      "exp_month": "10",
      "exp_year": "2017",
      "card_type": "MASTERCARD DEBIT",
      "bank": "GTBANK",
      "country_code": "NG",
      "brand": "MASTERCARD"
    },
    "customer": {
      "first_name": "BoJack",
      "last_name": "Horseman",
      "email": "bojack@horsinaround.com",
      "customer_code": "CUS_xnxdt6s1zg1f4nx",
      "phone": "",
      "metadata": {},
      "risk_action": "default"
    },
    "created_at": "2016-10-01T10:59:59.000Z"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in json library. For example:

```py
import json

#if your json is in file
dict_from_file = json.load(open("foo.json"))

#if your json is in a string
dict_from_string = json.loads(string)
```